# AOC AGON Curved Gaming Monitor Menus Randomly Pop Up

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I am having an issue with my computer monitor. The monitor is an `AOC AGON Curved Gaming Monitor 49" (AG493UCX)`. This was a gift from this past Christmas. The problem I am having relates to the menus which are seemingly appearing at random on screen without user input; this does not happen often so use of the monitor is acceptable.

The menus that pop up are the input and main menu. On some occasions the menu pops up and the menu selection changes. My initial troubleshooting focused on the remote control for the unit; I simply removed the batteries however this was not the source of the problem. This machine has been connected to two different computers and three different graphics cards and the problem has persisted across the board.

I looked online for some answers however and saw some common issues such as defective part; this includes the following potential cause:

A button/switch is stuck - there are buttons on the monitor for power, various menus including input. I have tested each button and found that non of them appear stuck or sticking.

I ended up reaching out to customer support. The pandemic caused the response times to be slow but the AOC customer support had me ship the unit back, an RMA, and once they received it the shipped a brand new unit; mind you this was not the original having been repaired but a brand new unit. Alas even with the new unit I still have the same issues.

It is feasible in my mind that a batch of parts was received by the manufacturer that resulted in a batch of monitors being adversely affected. However at this point I am inclined to think that there is some outside interference that is alluding me.

Any information, advice, or troubleshooting tips are greatly appreciated. I am hopeful this is something I can fix preventing me from needing to reach back out to the manufacturer.

For what its worth the current machine connected to it is running `Windows 10`, with an `i7`, and 48GB of RAM.

Comment: sort of an "outside of the box" question: is the remote line-of-sight and have you any other remotes that might be triggering the menu inadvertently? Are there any "passthrough" features enabled for controlling other connected devices (i think this is called HDMI-CEC)?

Comment: I pointed the remote at myself and was able to turn the monitor off and back on so ostensibly not line-of-sight. I am not familiar with HDMI-CEC however cursory review shows AOC calls it E-link; I do not see a reference at this time. This is connected by DisplayPort at the moment.